# Tableau javascript API throws always an error when using with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tableau-api

I'm writing a javascript code using #tableau-javascript-api to get data from Tableau server. I know it is frontend. Even that I'm looking for a way to automate my javascript code to execute. For that nodejs offers to automate javascript.

There are several ways to automate browser. For example phantom, slimer, puppeteer ect. These are not the issue at the moment. The problem is when I start any of my javascript code including "tableau-api" then I got error.
Please, help me what I should do.

Case 1:

```
var tableau = require('tableau-api');

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720})
  await page.goto('http://my_tableau_server/#/signin', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // wait until page load
  await page.type('[name="username"]', CREDS.username);
  slowMo: 500
  await page.type('[name="password"]', CREDS.password);
  // click and wait for navigation
  await Promise.all([
   page.click('[tb-test-id="button-signin"]'),
   page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),

  ]);
}
```

Error looks like:
C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\node_modules\tableau-api\index.js:1651
      global.HTMLElement = Element;
                           (^points to Element)

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\node_modules\tableau-api\index.js:1651:28
    at C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\node_modules\tableau-api\index.js:1662:5
    at Object. (C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\node_modules\tableau-api\index.js:9975:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

Case 2:

```
var tableau = require('C:\\Development\\DDH\\JavaScript API\\javascriptAPINPM\\tableau-2');
```

Error looks like:
C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\tableau-2.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { window.tableau = window.tableau || {};
                                                                                                 (^points to window)
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object. (C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\tableau-2.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object. (C:\Development\DDH\JavaScript API\javascriptAPINPM\init_jsdom.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)

Answer (score 1):

The Tableau Javascript API is designed to run in the browser, not in a NodeJS application.  Your NodeJS application should load an HTML page that uses the Tableau Javascript API.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've not found the way to fix it. But there are many offers to automate headless browser. At the moment I use puppeteer and try to connect puppeteer and tableau-javascript-api. I can log in to my tableau server over puppeteer. If you have an idea, pls let me know. It would be cool when I can manipulate tableau-javascript-api ^^

Comment: I have found the way to do my job. I exetude my tableau api code over puppeteer and use "localStroge" to get datas from tableau interface to the backend (node).